# Tensorflow NIH Chest X-ray CNN validation accuracy not improving even with regularization

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I’ve been working on a CNN that takes in a 224x224 grayscale xray image and outputs either 0 or 1 based on whether it detects an abnormality.

[This](https://nihcc.app.box.com/v/ChestXray-NIHCC) is the dataset I am using. I split the dataset into two with 106496 images for training and the remaining 5624 for validation. Since they’re both from the same dataset, they should both come from the same distribution.

I tried training the model I described above using the pretrained InceptionV3 and VGG19 architectures without success. I then tried making my own model similar to the VGG19 architecture.

I simplified the model as much as possible so that the training accuracy was above 90% and added various regularizers such as dropout and l2. I also tried different hyperparameters and image augmentation but the validation accuracy wouldn’t exceed 70% after 5-10 epochs. The validation loss doesn't seem to drop at all either.

Here are my accuracy vs epoch and loss vs epoch curves (pink is train, green in validation):

[image: acc vs epoch]

[image: loss vs epoch]

And here is my code:

```
def create_model(settings):
    """
    Create a basic model
    """
    # create model
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Input((224, 224, 1)))
    # block 1
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', use_bias=True, name='block1_conv'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool'))
    # block 2
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', use_bias=True, name='block2_conv'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool'))
    # block 3
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(192, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', use_bias=True, name='block3_conv1'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(192, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', use_bias=True, name='block3_conv2'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool'))
    # block 4
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(384, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', use_bias=True, name='block4_conv1'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(384, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', use_bias=True, name='block4_conv2'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(384, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', use_bias=True, name='block4_conv3'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool'))
    # block 5
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', use_bias=True, name='block5_conv1'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', use_bias=True, name='block5_conv2'))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', use_bias=True, name='block5_conv3'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool'))
    # fully connected
    model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='fc_pool'))   
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3, name='fc_dropout'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='fc_output'))
    
    # compile model
    model.compile(
        optimizers.SGD(
            learning_rate=settings["lr_init"],
            momentum=settings["momentum"],
        ),
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        metrics=[
            'accuracy',
            metrics.Precision(),
            metrics.Recall(),
            metrics.AUC()
        ]
    )
    model.summary()
    return model



def configure_callbacks(settings):
    """
    Create a list of callback objects
    """
    # tensorboard
    log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    tensorboard_callback = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
    
    # learning rate reduction on plateau
    lrreduce_callback = callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
        monitor='val_loss',
        factor=settings["lr_factor"],
        patience=settings["lr_patience"],
        min_lr=settings["lr_min"],
        verbose=1,
    )
    
    # save model
    checkpoint_callback = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath="saves/" + settings["modelname"] + "/cp-{epoch:03d}",
        monitor='val_accuracy',
        mode='max',
        save_weights_only=True,
        save_best_only=True,
        verbose=1,
    )
    return [tensorboard_callback, lrreduce_callback, checkpoint_callback]



def get_data(settings):
    """ 
    Create a generator that will be used for training
    """
    df=pd.read_csv("dataset/y_train_binary.csv")
    columns = [
        "Abnormal"
    ]
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255.,
        rotation_range=5,
        brightness_range=(0.9, 1.1),
        zoom_range=(1,  1.1),
    )
    # 94.983% for training (106496 = 64*6656)
    traindata = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=df[:NTRAIN],
        directory="dataset/images",
        x_col="Image Index",
        y_col=columns,
        color_mode='grayscale',
        batch_size=settings["batchsize"],
        class_mode="raw",
        target_size=(224,224),
        shuffle=True,
    )
    # 5.017% for testing (5624)
    testdata = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=df[NTRAIN:],
        directory="dataset/images",
        x_col="Image Index",
        y_col=columns,
        color_mode='grayscale',
        batch_size=settings["batchsize"],
        class_mode="raw",
        target_size=(224,224),
        shuffle=True,
    )
    return (traindata, testdata)



def newtrain(settings):
    """
    Create a new model "(modelname)" and train for (epoch) epochs
    """
    model = create_model(settings)
    callbacks = configure_callbacks(settings)
    traindata, testdata = get_data(settings)
    
    # train
    model.fit(
        x=traindata,
        epochs=settings["epoch"],
        validation_data=testdata,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        verbose=1,
    )
    model.save_weights(f"saves/{settings['modelname']}/cp-{settings['epoch']:03d}")
```

I’m running out of ideas and it takes half a day to train 50 epochs so I would appreciate if anyone knows how I can solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you do some **EDA** on [NIH Chest X-rays](https://www.kaggle.com/nih-chest-xrays/data) you may also see that there is a significant class imbalance issue among 14 classes. By your model definition, I can assume that you put a normal image on one side and an abnormal (`13` cases) on the other side. First of all, if this true, I would say, it's better to classify all cases - all are important in clinician practice.

- Shift to `14` cases classification

You're using your own design model, but you should first start with the pre-trained model. It's better and next you can gradually integrate your own idea.

- Use pretriend model, e.g `DenseNet`, `EfficientNet`, `NFNet` etc

In your data generator, you use `shuffle=True` for the test set, which is wrong, rather it should be `False`.

```
 testdata = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        ....
        target_size=(224,224),
         shuffle=False
```

For better control of your input pipeline, IMO, you should write your own custom data generator and experiment with advanced augmentation to prevent overfitting stuff.

Comment: I tried using pretrained models before with 14 classes but the accuracy turned out to be really low. I will see what I can do with writing my own generator.

Comment: When you adopt multi-class, then you can add various stuff like increasing the class samples or weighted the class losses.

Comment: Alright. I'll try the weighted losses. Also why do you set shuffle to False?

Comment: You should shuffle the training set but not the validation set and test set. https://forums.fast.ai/t/shuffle-true-or-false/1438/8

Comment: Sadly no the accuracy hasn’t improved

Comment: I see. The data set is also hosted on kaggle, can you share a notebook with what you've tried so far with the above approach?

Comment: Oh sorry I don't have a notebook. I just have a single py file.
So far I tried: using all 14 classes, Inception-V3, Resnet, VGG19, Adding dropout to conv/fc, adding l2 to conv/fc, adding batchnorm to conv/fc, reducing number of filters, reducing model complexity, (errored) changing to Sparse Categorical Cross Entropy Loss, and zooming in since the model seemed to be memorizing the random noise in the images (such as some of the texts and symbols)

Increasing the number of classes hurt the performance significantly and changing/editing the architecture barely had any effect